# How to append today's price in historical GoogleFinance prices to generate SPARKLINE?

Tags: array-merge, google-finance, sparklines

I am trying to make SPARKLINE in Google Sheet with this formula:

```
=SPARKLINE(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "close", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -100), TODAY()), , 2))
```

It shows a perfect line chart, but it fetches data till yesterday's date. I want today's live price append to this data. I can get today price with this formula:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","price")
```

For Example,

[image: e.g.]

But I don't know how to add today's price at the end of the old historical price so I can generate live SPARKLINE.

Please suggest a solution or you have any different approach to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=SPARKLINE({INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "close", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -100), TODAY()));today(),GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","price")})
```

Comment: Thanks. There was an error but I just have to delete the keyword "today()" which is after the semicolon. It worked!!!

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. It works on my side but could depend on local parameters. Glad to see you have been able to adapt it.